# SpEL for URI Evaluation in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to use SpEL when specifying a URI in a route?  I've tried this a few ways but doesn't seem to be working.

Would like to do something like:

```
<from uri="jms:queue:#{ ${mq.dynamic.switch} ? '$mq.dynamic.queue' : '$mq.static.queue'}?connectionFactory=#connectionFactory" />
```

I'm essentially trying to evaluate a property to determine what queues to leverage when configuring a JMS route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible in `<from>`. Howerver you can use Camel's property placeholders:
http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

And in Camel routes such as `<to>` you can use "dynamic-to" which allows to use any of the scripting languages such as SpEL also:

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html
- http://camel.apache.org/languages.html